# How long does Microsoft Office Graph API refresh token lives?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365

We've configured an AAD multi-tenant app and we are aquiring tokens from following endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token using the code we've got from user authorisation.

Endpoint provides no information about the refresh token lifetime.

This document states it should always have a default value of 90 days: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#refresh-and-session-token-lifetime-policy-properties

Is it always 90 days, can we be sure it'll live that long or it still depends on the user's organization configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, per the document unless you specify otherwise via conditional access the token lifetime is 90 days.